# Plot a function of a column with DataFrame.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to use `DataFrame.plot` to plot a function of a column, as in:

```py
base = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1,0,0,0)
dts = [base + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(hours=x) for x in range(24)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=dts, data=range(24), columns=['a'])

df.plot(use_index=True, y=np.cos(df.a)) # gives KeyError
```

?

Please note that I'd like to stick with `df.plot` since it's an easy one-liner which lets me handle temporal data quite easily.

Comment: You can just do `np.cos(df['a']).plot()`.

Comment: well, that was simple. thanks ! mind to write an answer ?